# Problem with an bootable usb

Tags: usb

I have ubuntu windows and i want to install new one,kali linux for example.
i tryed unetbootin program and it completes fine,after going to a boot menu and booting from usb,it gave me third time some unetbootin bluescreen and in the box over there is only an default option which aint do nothing,any advices?

Comment: Try to post a screenshot of that screen...

Comment: Im not sure i can make screenshot when im at bootmenu,but its simple bluescreen, middle of that is box where should be options,but theres only default named option which aint do nothing,keeps telling me you have 10 second to choose,i press enter it start counting again.But if i tryed to press some button it gave me the typing blimp down the corner,so im able to type there something if its helping,and up at middle is written unetbootin

Comment: okay i found one picture from online,there he have 2 option and default,which i have only default,link: http://basraayman.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/screen-shot-2013-07-16-at-11-51-20.png?w=510&h=268

Comment: Btw,i used before app named gparted,with that i changed the manage flags to boot and filesystem to fat32 on usb.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a different live usb creator instead of unetbootin. I have had issues with certain distros not being loaded properly onto the USB with unetbootin, but when i try a different program such as LiLi USB Creator or Universal USB Creator or Win32 Disk Imager then one of them usually does the trick. For Kali, they recommend you use Win32 Disk Imager if you are trying to set the live USB up thru windows. http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-live-usb-install

Comment: I cant open them at all with this ubuntu,wont let me open these exe files,and wine ruin it also.

Comment: You have ubuntu and windows correct? run the exe file to create the liveusb through your windows installation. Check out the link i provided - it walks you through how to create the image with linux by using the dd command

Comment: I have only ubuntu,tryng to get back to windows.

Comment: I misunderstood your post I'm sorry. You can create the image with linux still. just use the dd command. if you do not feel comfortable, read the manual by typing "man dd" in the terminal minus the quotes.

Comment: im to beginner,maybe you want to help me through skype or smthing

Comment: I can help thru this as I am able to. Provide me some answers to these questions please: What size USB are you using? Provide a Screenshot of the result of the command "sudo -i fdisk -l" with the USB plugged in? What is the exact file name of your kali download?